# What are the bounties of the Yonko?

Tags: one-piece

We know that the *Yonko* are one of the three great powers of the One Piece World. Though they are the four emperors ruling the second half of grand line, they are still *Pirates* in the eyes of the world government with some bounties set for each of them.

So can somebody tell what the current bounties (as of Jan 2020) of the present/past yonkos are?

Bounties for the guys I'm looking for:

- Edward Newgate, Whitebeard (now deceased)
- "Red-Haired" Shanks
- Charlotte Linlin, Big Mom
- Kaido of the Beasts
- Marshall D. Teach, Blackbeard (took over as the Yonko after WB's death)

Note: Like the *Shichibukai*, even the Yonkos might not have their bounties active (I do not know for sure), but certainly there must be a bounty on them which would determine their strengths, influence and importance (need a case arise when one of them is dethroned).

Comment: I've re-worded the question and asked for the bounties as of 2017. That is not up for debate as [the accepted answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/7311/1604) shows. If the bounty is not revealed, then it should say "Not Revealed" which is correct as of 2017. Therefore, marking to re-open the question.

Comment: Now apparantly they are,

Comment: See:  http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Bounties  not for all, some.

Comment: They have now been revealed (https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_957)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! Their bounties have been revealed as of [chapter 957](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_957).

The amounts are as follow:

**Kaido:**

> B. 4,611,100,000

**Charlotte Linlin:**

> B. 4,388,000,000

**Shanks:**

> B. 4,048,900,000

**Marshall D. Teach:**

> B. 2,247,600,000

**Whitebeard:**

> B. 5,046,000,000

**Gol D. Roger:**

> B. 5,564,800,000

[Color comment](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Ope_Ope_no_Mi): The marines formerly made an offer of **B. 5,000,000,000** for the Ope-Ope no mi.

Answer (score 5):

[Bounties for Yonkos haven't been shown till now](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Yonko). And IMO, for someone as powerful as a Yonko, bounties doesn't matter much. Bounties are set so that some bounty hunter would be tempted to capture them. But yonkos being one of the most powerful forces in OP, no one would dare to capture a Yonko.

WhiteBeard- Not revealed.

Shanks- Not revealed.

Big Mam- Not revealed.

Kaido- Not revealed.

Blackbeard- Not given any bounty.

Comment: *Bounties are set so that some bounty hunter would be tempted to capture them.* - The Shichibukai have bounties too, but they are not currently active as they work for the World govt. Gecko Moria was defeated by Luffy but the WG didn't capture him because he did not go against them. Thus, even the Yonko must have some bounty on their heads, say one day, they are de-throned and the govt is then interested in capturing them, thereby just activating their bounties again.

Comment: well for shichibukai its true. but for yonkos, even if WG has some bounty, how does it affect their status as yonko? The shichibukai have a pact with WG so their bounties are not active. Yonkos don't have such pact with WG.

Comment: updated with link. in the link, the bounty status shows- NA (not available).

Comment: When they introduce a Shichibukai it always states 'former' bounty so it is the bounty they had before becoming a Shichibukai. (Which kind of makes sense or Doflamingo's would have been much higher)

Comment: It is worth noting that in all but one cases the bounties are "dead or alive".  While capturing would be insane we have actually seen multiple assassination attempts on Whitebeard (by Ace actually).

Comment: Recently a few were released. see http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Bounties

Comment: As of chapter 959, these bounties are known.

Answer (score 0):

None of the Youkou Bounties have been shown so far.

But Since Charlotte Katakuri's bounty is 1057 million bellies, You can expect Big Mom's bounty to be in the range of 1.5 Billion to 2.5 Billion.

Assuming BM's is close to 2 Billion, Shanks and Kaidou might have a bounty close to 2.5 to 3 Billion.

Since Black Beard is still new, we can expect his Bounty to be close to Big Mom at around 2 Billion. But expect his bounty to surpass Kaidou and Shanks once both are defeated.

Comment: http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Bounties

Comment: Black Beard never had one. Maybe now after the Impel Down Arc

Comment: That was before time-skip. 2 years after that, he definitely will have a bounty.